# VB.NET call ADODB.Command.Execute - not returning Recordset

Tags: vb.net, ado

I have a classic ADO command which execs a sproc and returns a RecordSet.  This is being executed from a VB.NET using the PIA.

However when I .Execute the command, the result returned is not an ADODB.Recordset but a System.__ComObject.

Wonder if anyone has seen similar behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't that just the .NET interop wrapper for any COM object? [`GetType.Type` will always return `System.__ComObject`](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/320523). You can [`TryCast`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyy863x8(VS.80).aspx) or `DirectCast` to a more useful type.

Comment: You're spot on.  I found out that I needed to make sure that the methods passing this recordset about were all strongly typed, or else it would fall over at runtime.